# Swap text around a character

Tags: notepad++, text-editor

I have lines of text following the same format:

`Title1 : Text1
 Title2 : Text2`

How can I swap the text at both sides of `:` to the other side? Like:

`Text1 : Title1
 Text2 : Title2`

I can write a small script to do this but I was wondering if there is an quicker way to do it with Regex, a built in functionality or any other magic?

Comment: Are there leading/trailing spaces to handle? If yes, use `^(\h*\w+)(\h*:\h*)(\w+\h*)$` -> `$3$2$1` regex replacement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Can't find any text. Let me give you more details about the lines. They are all in this format: `Homepage (homepage): http://www.example.com/`

Comment: Aha, that is a different kettle of fish. Use `^([^\r\n:]+)(:\h*)(.*)$` and use the same replacement. Or `^([^\r\n:]+)(:\h*)([^:\r\n]+)$`

Comment: Woow that did the trick !!. Can you explain `$3$2$1` part?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Please write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am on a mobile, and typing on it is not my strong point :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^([^\r\n:]+)(:\h*)(.*)$
```

or

```
^([^\r\n:]+)(:\h*)([^:\r\n]+)$
```

Replace with `$3$2$1` where the `$n` are backreferences to the values captured with the capturing groups. The groups are numbered automatically in the order they appear in the pattern.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `([^\r\n:]+)` - Group 1 later referenced to as `$1` capturing one or more  chars other than CR, LF and colon
- `(:\h*)` - Group 2 capturing a colon and zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `([^:\r\n]+)` -Group 3 referenced to as `$3` later. See above.
- `$` - end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Hold Alt button on the keyboard and highlight the 3rd column i.e. Text1. This will select the entire 3 column.

Step 2: Right Click and choose 'Cut' and then Paste in front of the 1st column.

Step 3: Hold Alt button on the keyboard and highlight the ':' column.

Step 4: Right Click and choose 'Cut' and then Paste in between the 1st and 2nd column.

Comment: There are no columns. These are texts in lines.

Comment: If there are not columns, it should still work.Have you tried holding the alt button and highlighting the text after the ':' ?

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. These lines are in different length, so I can't select it that way.